# Sending SMS trough a modem attached to another server using ser2net and socat

Tags: usb, modem, mobile, socat, sms

I don't know exactly how to troubleshoot the issue I'm having, so I'll ask here.

I have a USB 3G modem attached to a physical machine `server4` running ProxMox OS based on Debian Wheezy, and I can send SMS with it just fine using `gsmsendsms`.

```
echo "Message" | gsmsendsms -d /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 19200 <phone number>
```

This works well. Now I have a virtual machine (Ubuntu Server 14.04) installed on a different physical server `server1` also running Proxmox based on Debian Wheezy, and I want this virtual machine to access the USB modem on `server4`.

So far I've tried using `ser2net` on `server4` to 'share' the USB modem trough the network using this line in `config`:

```
2000:raw:0:/dev/ttyUSB0:19200 8DATABITS NONE 1STOPBIT banner
```

which should do the job from what I've managed to understand about `ser2net`.

On the virtual machine I tried using `socat` to add a virtual device linked to shared USB modem:

```
socat pty,link=/dev/virtualcom0,raw tcp:server4:2000
```

which seems to do the job, as the device `virtualcom0` appears in `/dev`. However, if I try to send an SMS using `virtualcom0`, I get a funny error:

```
user@vm:~$ echo "SMS Test Message!" | sudo gsmsendsms -d /dev/virtualcom0 -b 19200 <phone number>
gsmsendsms[ERROR]: clearing DTR failed (errno: 22/Invalid argument)
```

I use the exact same command as on physical server where USB modem is connected, but it fails, and googling 'gsmsendsms errno 22' wasn't very productive.

In the end, I'd like to make a USB modem plugged into the physical `server4` accessible for Zabbix, which runs in a virtual machine on `server1`. If there is a better way of doing this than using `ser2net` and `socat`, I'm ready to try something else.

Comment: Hardware handshaking is probably not supported over network. Try the `-X` option of gsmsendsms or access the real device directly via sshfs.

Comment: Thanks, `-X` was a part of solution, I got it to work, just not using `gsmsendsms` but sending text directly onto the device with some flags and all that. Now I have a problem because I can't access this `virtualcom0` as a normal user, only as root.

Comment: Nevermind, I got that too, I just had to execute `socat` command as user not as root, and mount the `virtualcom0` in `$HOME` directory instead of `/dev`.